# How to display list of posts from particular month

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to set up an archives page, and I have the following code that creates a list of archives by month:

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
```

So, when I click on a month, it takes me to the page "/?m=201309", but the template for this page is my home page. How do I customise that page to list the posts by that month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create archives.php and design it accordingly.

Check this awesome tutorial by tut plus and all your queries would be solved.

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-wordpress-archives-template-for-your-theme/